# Arrays of paired strings?

Tags: java

I have method that checks for duplicate values in an ArrayList, I want it to return the names of those EzVarIntegers (contains a name and a value among other things irrelevant for now) that contain duplicate values.

I was thinking of using two arrays side-by-side that have the names of EzVarIntegers with duplicate values on the same index. So that two EzVarIntegers with the same value X would be in ArrayOne[k] and ArrayTwo[k].

I'm quite new to this though so I'm wondering if there's any smarter way of handling this?

```
public ArrayList<String> dupCheck(ArrayList<EzVarInteger> RoiNumbs) {
    ArrayList<String> Dups = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int j=0;j<RoiNumbs.size();j++) {
        for (int k=j+1;k<RoiNumbs.size();k++) {
            if (k!=j && RoiNumbs.get(k).getValue() == RoiNumbs.get(j).getValue()) {
                //TODO see question
            }
        }
    }

    return Dups;
}
```

Comment: 2 possible ways to do it smarter are: 1) use a set, put the values into it and whenever `add(...)` returns that the value already was present you have a duplicate, 2) sort the array and then just check adjacent elements, i.e. whenever the elements at `i` and `i + 1` are equal you have a duplicate.

Comment: You should provide at least a mock EzVarInteger Class to demonstrate the problem, with 3 or 4 sample data collections, some of them dupes, to test the algo. [mcve]. Input, expected output. Note, that by convention, we write variable names in lower case. We don't care, what you do privately, but for fast understanding, sticking to such conventions (Dups, RoiNumbs)  is helpful and would show some respect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a Map (see Example)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

strings.add("a");
strings.add("b");
strings.add("a");
strings.add("c");

Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

for (String str : strings)
  {
    if (!(counts.containsKey(str)))
      {
        counts.put(str, 1);
      } 
  }

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet())
  {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
  }
```

}

Comment: I guess this is supposed to calculate how often a string appears and save that as a value in the map. But you kind of forgot the else block. currently this code will allways produce a count of 1 for everything.

Comment: Yes. just to show how with a Map he could easly handle duplicated values.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a Set to check for duplicates. So,

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
List<String> duplicateList = new ArrayList<>();

//if it is not present in the set then add it. If it present then add the  //name of the EzVarInteger object in the output list

for(EzVarInteger ez: RoiNumbs){
   if(!set.contains(ez.getValue)){
       set.add(ez.getValue());
   }else{
       duplicateList.add(ez.getName());
   }
}

//print the duplicate names
   for(String name:duplicateList){
      System.out.println(name);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you propose has a computational cost O (n * n)

You can sort the list. Which is done in O (n * log (n)). Then iterate through it to find the duplicate elements. Which is done in O (n). In this way the algorithm has a computational cost of O (n * log (n)), which is more optimal.